# Textarea with icon bootstrap is not align correct

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, alignment, textarea

I am creating bootstrap contacting form similar as this: http://amitpatil.me/demos/twitter-bootstrap-ajax-contact-form/contact.php

So far I have this in body:

```
<div class="container">

    <form role="form" style="width:400px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <h1>Contact us</h1>

        <div class="form-group required-field-block">                
            <div class="col-md-12 input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></span>
                <input type="text" size="30" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Podjetje">
                <div class="required-icon">
                    <div class="text">*</div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group required-field-block">       
            <div class="col-md-12 input-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 column">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-11 column">
                    <textarea rows="3" size="30" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Sporočilo"></textarea>  
                    <div class="required-icon">
                        <div class="text">*</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary razmik_mail">Pošlji</button>

    </form>
```

But this done this:

[image]

As you can see my "Textarea" is not align correctly. Icon shoud be below (info icon) and full icon, as you can see, it has cut icon, I do not know why. And textarea shoud be aling with input, and little longer (as is in link up).

So my goal is to create textarea like this:

[image]

Any idea, where I am wrong? Realy thanks for help.

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tutpgtdo/5/

Comment: It's hard to help you without actual demo.

Comment: give me a second, i will create Fiddle

Comment: here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tutpgtdo/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have extra column HTML around your textarea, remove that and it should be fine, so it should look like this:

```
<div class="form-group required-field-block">       
        <div class="col-md-12 input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>
            <textarea rows="3" size="30" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Sporočilo"></textarea>  
                <div class="required-icon">
                    <div class="text">*</div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Icon is widespread across the entire textarea. I need that icon is same size as other icons. Like in example in url that I post. I have add picture in my Question, to see, what your code do.

Comment: in other words, your solution looks much better :D thanks for help